# Use residues to evaluate the definite integrals in

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\int \limits_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{\cos^23\theta\,\mathrm d\theta}{5-4\cos2\theta}=\dfrac {3\pi}8$$

Use residues to evaluate the definite integrals.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is this for homework?  Have you been able to at least state what residues are and how they may help you with integrals like the one above?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $\gamma\colon [0,2\pi]\to \mathbb C, \theta \mapsto e^{i\theta}$. Prove that $$\int \limits_0^{2\pi}\dfrac{(\cos(3\theta))^2}{5-4\cos(2\theta)}\mathrm d\theta=\dfrac 1{4i}\int _\gamma\dfrac{(z^6+1)^2}{-2z^9+5z^7-2z^5}\mathrm dz.$$

The residues given by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=res%28%28z%5E6%2B1%29%5E2%2F%28-2z%5E9-2z%5E5%2B5z%5E7%29%29) confirm the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

I can give you a few hints, unless this is not homework and then I will fill in some details.  First of all, you can use the fact that, for any $y$:

$$\cos{y} = \frac12 \left (e^{i y}+e^{-i y}\right )$$

So let $z=e^{i x}$, and $dx=-i dz/z$.  This turns the real integral into a contour integral that may be evaluated using the residue theorem.  Now, I will just show the result, you will need to do some algebra.

$$\frac{i}{4} \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z^5} \frac{\left (z^6+1\right)^2}{2 z^4-5 z^2+2}$$

The integral, according to the residue theorem, is $i 2 \pi$ times the sum of the residues of the poles inside $|z|=1$.  You will have to show that the poles are at $z=0$, $z=\pm \sqrt{2}$, and $z=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$.  Off these poles, only the ones at $z=0$ and $z=\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$ have residues that count toward the value of the integral.

How do you compute the value of the residues?  For the simple poles (those at $\pm 1/\sqrt{2}$), I will give you an easy way to compute them if you do not know it yet.

> Let $f(z) = p(z)/q(z)$ and $z_0$ be a simple zero of $q$.  Then the
>   residue of $f$ at $z=z_0$ is $p(z_0)/q'(z_0)$.

So in this case, plugging in $z=1/\sqrt{2}$, the residue is $-i 27/64$.  For $z=-1/\sqrt{2}$, I get the same value.

For the pole at $z=0$, however, we have a difficulty because the pole is *fifth* order.  In this case, the easiest thing to do is to simply find the coefficient of $z^4$ in the rational function piece of the integrand.  The Taylor expansion is actually not terrible:

$$\frac{\left (z^6+1\right)^2}{2 z^4-5 z^2+2} = \frac12 \left (1+2 z^6 + z^{12}\right) \left [1+\left (\frac{5}{2} z^2-z^4 \right )+\left (\frac{5}{2} z^2-z^4 \right )^2+\cdots \right ] $$

You should be able to see that the coefficient of $z^4$ in this expansion is $21/8$.  Thus the integral is

$$i 2 \pi \left (i \frac{21}{32} - 2 i \frac{27}{64} \right ) = \frac{3 \pi}{8}$$

as asserted.